# How to translate data in dict

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, translation, data-analysis

Morning guys!

I have this tiny part of my code which should be translated:

```
meta_dict = dict(zip(meta.column_names, meta.column_labels))
```

If you guys want to see what is inside it and how the data is structure, it is:

```
{'record': 'Record number',
'date': 'Completion time and date',
'Language': 'Millises keeles eelistaksite sellele küsimustikule vastata?На каком языке вы бы
предпочли ответить на этот опрос?',
'age': 'Palun märkige oma vanus täisaastates',
'gender': 'Palun märkige oma sugu',
'age_group': 'Age groups',
'age_group2': 'Age group 2',
'T3': 'Mis rahvusest Te olete?',
[...]
```

There's more down to be translated in this meta data:

My problem is, I'm struggling with how could I translate this whole data. This is the loop I'm trying to run:

```
for mnc, mnl in zip(meta.column_names, meta.column_labels):
   GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(x)
```

When I run it, I get this error here:
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Could you guys give me a help?

Comment: paste the full traceback, also some real code... `translate(x)` ...what is `x`?

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary to convert the dataframe into a dictionary?

You could just apply the translation directly on the df columns respectively:

```
meta[column_label].apply(lambda x: GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(x))
```